# ember run loop screws computed property assertions up or is it

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, node.js, angularjs, ember.js

In the route, I wait for a promise and set the controller property. I do this in `renderTemplate` hook method.

`File: play_route.js`

```
App.PlayRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    renderTemplate: function() {
        var ctrl = this.controllerFor('play.index');

        return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve) {
            ctrl.set('game', {});
            resolve();
        });
    }
});
```

In the controller I have a computed property `isLoading` that checks the `game` property if it's `null`, so if the promise (from`renderTemplate`) is resolved `isLoading` should be true.

Also I have an action that accesses the `game` property.

`File: play_controller.js`

```
App.PlayController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    game: null,

    isLoading: function() {
        return this.get('game') === null;
    }.property('game'),

    actions: {
        startGame: function() {
            this.get('game').access();
        }
    }
});
```

`game` property is `null` in the beggining so the `startGame` action would throw, but if `isLoading` is `false` then it is safe to call `startGame`.

Finally the template makes sure the `startGame` action is `hidden` until the `isLoading` property is `false`.

`File: play_template.hbs`

```
<div {{bind-attr class="isLoading:hidden"}}>
    <div {{action 'startGame'}}>
    </div>
</div>
```

This works fine, but when the page loads, if i click `startGame div`in the first couple of seconds of its appearance, it throws `game is null` error. (as if `isLoading` property is not respected).

So the question is: is it theoretically possible that following assumptions doesn't hold. Maybe because of emberjs run loop awkwardness or something.

1. `game` property is null.
2. `isLoading` computed property is true.
3. `game` property is set to Object.
4. `isLoading` computed property is false.

My problem is the 4th step, which is when `isLoading` is false only then i can click the `startGame` action, but it still throws `game is null` error.

Answer (score 0):

The `renderTemplate` hook doesn't make any promise to wait on a promise returned to it.  In fact it doesn't even care about anything returned from it.  Possibly you don't care about that either.

If you have a promise that you need to block the transition, you'll need to return it to either `beforeModel`, `model`, or `afterModel`.

Additionally it looks like you're using the `play` controller/route etc, but you are trying to fetch the `play.index` controller and modifying it.  So I'd guess `game` would stay null inside your `play` controller forever.

Comment: I use Rendertemplate because I need the Dom elements. The promise is not important, I simplified the code, but think of it as an Ajax call. My question is when I set the game to Object, and when the computed properties fire, is it theoretically possible the game is still null, at some point.

Comment: And yeah my mistake simplifying the code but route is in fact play.index so that's not an issue as well.